# c++ vector equivalent of this array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

What is the equivalent of this array code as a vector? Random is just a random number not too important.

```
 Array[random - 1] = Array[random - 1] + 1;
```

Below is what I'm trying and says Must have pointer to object type. I had this working a few days ago and I cannot remember how I had it.

```
Vector.at[random - 1] = Vector.at[random - 1] + 1;
```

Comment: When that second example compiles, what does the compiler tell you?

Answer (score 1):

The `operator[]` (subscript operator) is overloaded for `std::vector` so you can simply do:

```
vec[random-1] = vec[random-1] + 1;
```

Or,

```
vec.at(random-1) = vec.at(random-1) + 1;
```

if you want to use `at` method instead.

Also, note this is equivalent to (shorter code):

```
vec[random-1]++;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: it's important to note that `at` and `operator[]` for STL containers are slightly different. `at` will throw an `out_of_range` exception if the subscript index is out of range while `operator[]` will not.

Comment: Subscript isn't **required** to throw an exception when the argument is out of bounds. The behavior is undefined, so throwing an exception is allowed.